# Dynamically require with browserify and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browserify

I'm trying to `require` files dynamically iterating a json and call them with the `require` method, unfortunately it cannot read the module for some unknown reason. Why it fail to require the module if that exists?

I created a file `json` where I will list my requirement `paths` that browserify should require.

```
{
"vendor": {
        "angular-translate" : "angular-translate",
        "angular-sanitize" : "angular-sanitize.min",
        "ui-boostrap" : "ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min",
        "dialogs" : "dialogs"
    }
}
```

Then I created a file that iterate this `json` and try to require the path of it like so:

**package.js**

```
var dependencies = require('./../dependencies');

    module.exports = function(angular) {

        angular.forEach(dependencies.vendor, function(value,key) {

            var path = '../vendor/' + value;

            require('./' + path);
        });
    }
```

The on the main file `app.js` I require the `package.js` in this way:

```
var angularJs = require('angular');

require('./package.js')(angular);
```

After the `browserifycation` the chrome console give me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './../vendor/angular-translate'

How can require those file listed in my json file?

Comment: Unfortunately `browserify` won't work with dynamic paths. The paths should be hard-coded.

Comment: oh, that's a bad news :( there is no work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Browserify does static analysis of your code. It can't follow dynamic requires because it's not involved at all during runtime.